# Bayes factor from posterior odds

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, model-comparison, bayes-factors

I tried to answer my own question [Comparing two Bayesian models under disjoint prior supports using MCMC](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187074/comparing-two-bayesian-models-under-disjoint-prior-supports-using-mcmc). Here is my intent. I am not confident in what I  wrote so prefer to post it as a question : Is this a correct way to compute Bayes factor ?

I would like to compute the Bayes factor:
 $$  K = \frac{P(x|H_1)}{P(x|H_2)} =\frac{P(H_1|x)}{P(H_2|x)} \frac{P(H_2)}{P(H_1)}  $$

I have a model consisting of three parameters $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$ and $\theta_3$.  $H_1$ is $\{(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3) \in [m,M]^3  \mbox{ such that } \theta_1<\theta_2<\theta_3\}$, $H_2$ is it complementary. 
Then suppose that I have a model to infer $P(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3 | x)$ under the complete parameter space $H_1 \cup H_2 $ then $P(H_1|x)$ can simply 
be computed as:
$$
P(H_1|x)=\int_m^M P(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3|x) 1_{\theta_1>\theta_2>\theta_3}(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3) d\theta_1 d\theta_2 d\theta_3
$$
by simply counting the posterior MCMC samples satisfying the condition and $P(H_2|x)=1-P(H_1|x)$.

So it remains to extract the associated $\frac{P(H_2)}{P(H_1)}$ by simply considering the subpart of $H_1$ over the overall parameter space:
$$
P(H_1)=\int p(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3) \cdot 1_{\theta_1>\theta_2>\theta_3}(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3) d\theta_1 d\theta_2 d\theta_3 
$$
which can be computed analytically for the prior $p(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$ associated to my posterior and again $
P(H_2)=1-p(H_1)$.

Is this a correct way to compute Bayes factor ? If yes, is this method has a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a correct approach indeed, since you compare two subsets of the parameter space after selected a prior for the entire parameter set. This prior indeed defines single-handedly prior weights on both subsets $H_0$ and $H_1$, which can be computed by integration. (If the three parameters are exchangeable, the prior weight of $H_0$ is $1/3!$.)

Comment: Thanks again. Have you a reference in mind for this approach ?

Comment: This is standard practice when considering null hypotheses that have a non zero weight under the original prior. There is no specific name or reference for this.