# Testing for the ordering of several means

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, multiple-comparisons

We have delineated 4 groups into a population and have a theory according to
which the distributions of a certain characteristic of this popular are ordered in the sense that $\mu_i > \mu_{i+1}$ for all $i$ ($\mu_i$ being the mean of the characteristic for population $i$). We thus acquired data for the 4 groups (with $N=20,25,30,100$ respectively) and observe the four densities : each have a quasi gaussian shape, each group with its proper variance.

We now would like to test our hypothesis that $\mu_1>\mu_2>\mu_3>\mu_4$. To do that I would like to test $H_1: \mu_1>\mu_2>\mu_3>\mu_4$ against it complementary $H_2$ using Bayes factor (I have another question [Bayes factor from posterior odds](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192947/bayes-factor-from-posterior-odds) for this particular point...). My question here is : are there more "standard" test to achieve my purpose ?

Comment: Likelihood ratio test?

Comment: There are indeed some standard tests for this situation, see my answer to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169419/why-bother-looking-at-an-omnibus-anova-when-i-have-a-priori-hypotheses-about-gro/169452#169452            That answer isn't really finnished, but I am out of time for a few days now.  Also, see the following book:   http://www.amazon.com/Constrained-Statistical-Inference-Inequality-Constraints/dp/0471208272/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1454110094&sr=1-4&keywords=order-restricted+inference